# Get commands phing executes / factor out phing

Tags: php, xml, phing

Is there a way to get the resulting commands that phing executes as the result of running a build file, or convert a `build.xml` file to a bash script?

Im thinking of moving to just bash scripts for building.

Comment: Can you test with `-debug` ? I think phing will echo all commands

Comment: @LP154 Sounds good, allow me to try

Comment: I tried, works with `-debug` + `-verbose`. I posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

By using :

```
phing -debug -verbose
```

You will have all a lot of information including the commands and the arguments, but also a lot of other debugging stuff.